# How to build an usb c to micro usb cable?

Tags: usb, wireless, charging, usb-c

I bougth a new phone, it came with usb type c charger, i mean there's a usb c port on the charger and a usb c to usb c cable. I had a wireless charging base wich i want to use with my new phone, this base can handle wireless fast charging if you provide a charger with 9v output, but it has a micro usb connector.

Tried to make a cable splitting two other cables, usb c to A and a micro usb to A but the charging pad never worked.

Got an adapter from usb c to usb A and a usb A to micro usb cable and it works but only in normal mode of wireless charging not fast charging.

Tried with my wife's charger from another brand, wich has an usb A port and a usb A to micro usb cable and it charges at fast speed as intended.

Can some one tell me how can I build an usb c to micro usb cable that works at fast charge? Of course I could get a cable but must tell, I couldn't find that type of cable in my country, and not so easy to get from US or other countries.

Comment: Can you point us at the technical specification of the wireless charger? That might help verify @Hearth's guess.

Comment: @Codo this is the one [link](https://www.qwikfone.com/uk/trade/vidvie-wlc1402-wireless-qi-charging-bracket-output-10w-with-usb-cable.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the standard (QC, USB PD, proprietary) is not mentioned. But since it works with a USB-A outlet, it's likely QC (as mentioned in accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to be able to. Your USB-C power adapter probably uses the USB Power Delivery standard, which requires the use of USB-C. Your fast-charge compatible wireless charger can't use USB PD, since it isn't using USB-C, so it probably is using Qualcomm QC, which is incompatible with USB PD.